# Command Handler with Sub-Categorized folders

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is the command handler I'm currently using, and it works as it's supposed to.

```js
try {
  let ops = {
    active: active
  }

  let commandFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`)
  commandFile.run(client, message, args, ops);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

But as you can see, it just reads into the commands folder and pulls the `.js` files from there.
What I'm looking to do, is to have the commands be sub-categorized for my own "OCD" purposes, so that I can keep track of them better on my end.
Is there any way with this command handler to do so?

Also, I've already tried [`discord.js-commando`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-commando) and I don't personally like the command structure it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`require-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all) package.

Let's assume that you have a file structure like the following:

```js
commands:
  folder1:
    file1.js
  folder2:
    subfolder:
      file2.js
```

You can use `require-all` to require all those files altogether:

```js
const required = require('require-all')({
  dirname: __dirname + '/commands', // Path to the 'commands' directory
  filter: /(.+)\.js$/, // RegExp that matches the file names
  excludeDirs: /^\.(git|svn)|samples$/, // Directories to exclude
  recursive: true // Allow for recursive (subfolders) research
});
```

The above `required` variable will look like this:

```js
// /*export*/ represents the exported object from the module
{
  folder1: { file1: /*export*/ },
  folder2: { 
    subfolder: { file2: /*export*/ } 
  }
}
```

In order to get all the commands you need to scan that object with a recursive function:

```js
const commands = {};

(function searchIn(obj = {}) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    const potentialCommand = obj[key];

    // If it's a command save it in the commands object
    if (potentialCommand.run) commands[key] = potentialCommand;
    // If it's a directory, search recursively in that too
    else searchIn(potentialCommand);
  }
})(required);
```

When you want to execute the command, simply call:

```js
commands['command-name'].run(client, message, args, ops)
```

You can find a working demo (with strings) at [this](https://repl.it/@FedericoGrandi/Discord-command-parsing) repl.

Comment: In with this coding, where would I put this the `let ops = { active: active }`? I need that for my queue system

Comment: You can put before the `commands['command-name'].run(...)`, just like you did before

Comment: Sidenote not about this question: I saw you left some of your questions unanswered (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603675/typeerror-in-pause-command), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354201/turn-queue-list-into-an-embed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203742/using-a-custom-emoji-based-on-the-user-presence-status-in-a-messageembed)): could you accept an answer to close them or post and accept a new answer explaining what have you done to solve it?

Comment: Where would I put `commands['command-name'].run(...)`? Inside each command or under the require-all?

Comment: Okay so, scratch that, I got it to detect my command as well as work with my permission system, however, when I run the command, it doesn't respond in the channel, nor does it throw any error's in the console. Any advice? I'd be more than happy to post a pastebin link of my `message.js` and my `app.js`

Comment: Try to put a console.log here and there to see what's the part that doesn't get running. Having the code would be useful

Comment: So, scratch that again, I got two commands to work so far that I've put in. The only problem is, when I run one command, it runs both of them. Do I need to have `commands['command-name'].run(...)` for each command? Or is there a way that it can pull all commands? Cause [this](https://pastebin.com/pCb5YsGA) happens in the console, which makes it look like the commands are put together instead of being seperate.

Comment: Can you post your `message.js` and `app.js`? If your command is `'ping'` then you're accessing `commands['ping']` so it should be ok.

Comment: I don't have a `message.js`, I figured just to have it in the `app.js` right now so i can more easily focus on getting it working and then move it to a `message.js` file. But, [here](https://pastebin.com/qywxEwQY) is the link to that. The ping command works fine, but I don't know what to do when putting in other commands. Do I make a new `commands['command-name'].run(...)` or what cause I tried that with a `stats` command and it loaded both when I ran it.

Comment: First problem with your code: you put the part that loads the commands inside the message handler, while it should be executed only once. If your commands run only when the `run` function is called then there's no way they get fired simultaneously: the files themselves will be required together (only once), but the command executed will be only the one that has that name. You can check that [here](https://pastebin.com/A2LV8kwZ)

Comment: So I attempted what you said and the commands aren't running, nor is there an error in the console

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. Where you had `if (typeof potentialCommand == 'string') commands[key] = potentialCommand;`, it wasn't working, but when I changed it to `if (potentialCommand.run) commands[key] = potentialCommand;` from what you posted in the original answer, it works, and now my commands are working properly.

Comment: Happy to hear that