# I was wondering if it was possible to use a switch statement in a json file

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

So I wanna make my index.js look cleaner, so I thought it would be cleaner, if the commands (switch statements) were in another file, so now Im wondering if I could somehow put them in a json file, or (if that isnt possible) insid a another js file and then somehow import it into index.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I code event/command handlers for my Discord.js bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548550/how-do-i-code-event-command-handlers-for-my-discord-js-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a JSON file, but you can do it in a js file.

Here is an example:

1- Create a file called helper.js

2- Add this code inside of it:

```
module.exports = {
// example function
biggerThanFive: array => {
    return array.filter(elem => {
        return elem > 5;
    });
}
```

}

3- In the index.js file require the helper file like this:

```
const helpers = require("./helper");
```

4- Call the function and give it a value like this:

```
helper.biggerThanFive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
// [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Im trying to make something like this https://pastebin.com/vDhitXUL, it just wont accept the message.channel.send. Thats what it looks like with a switch statement: https://pastebin.com/cBVE77fL

Comment: You mean you created a file and did this: 
module.exports = {
message.channel.send (// rest of the code )
}

Comment: Ok, in the file you created message is not defined. you have to define it first.
what you could do is send it as a parameter like I did above. I created a function and passed the array as a parameter: 
helper.biggerThanFive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).

Comment: This is what I mean:
module.exports = {
 // example function
 yourFunction: message => {
  message.channel.send({
   embed: {
    color: 3447003,
    title: "Help:",
    fields: [{ name: "Commands", value: "<commands>", inline: true }]
   }
  });
 }
};

// here how you call it and pass the message value.
helper.yourFunction(message)