# Count how many times a message has been sent with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just wanted to know if there's a way to count how many times a message has been sent in my Discord server, so the bot can send a message. I'm new with coding, so I don't know many things. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

To store the amount of messages sent in a guild, you'll have to keep track of a count somehow. Each time a message is sent, you can increment it by 1. Then, upon a user's request, you can display that number.

One easy option would be to store this "message count" for each guild inside of a JSON file. However, this would greatly impact performance. Consider a database for *much* better speeds and reliability.

**Example Setup**

*Before using this system, create a `guilds.json` file with a blank object (`{}`).*

Declaring the necessary variables...

```js
const fs = require('fs'); // fs is the built-in Node.js file system module.
const guilds = require('./guilds.json'); // This path may vary.
```

Adding the system to the `message` event listener...

```js
client.on('message', message => {
// If the author is NOT a bot...
  if (!message.author.bot) {
    // If the guild isn't in the JSON file yet, set it up.
    if (!guilds[message.guild.id]) guilds[message.guild.id] = { messageCount: 1 };
    // Otherwise, add one to the guild's message count.
    else guilds[message.guild.id].messageCount++;

    // Write the data back to the JSON file, logging any errors to the console.
    try {
      fs.writeFileSync('./guilds.json', JSON.stringify(guilds)); // Again, path may vary.
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

Using the system in a command...

```js
// Grab the message count.
const messageCount = guilds[message.guild.id].messageCount;

// Send the message count in a message. The template literal (${}) adds an 's' if needed.
message.channel.send(`**${messageCount}** message${messageCount !== 1 ? 's' : ''} sent.`)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: @Kikkiu The code for the command needs access to the `message` parameter from the event. It should either be set up within the `message` event listener, or inside of a command file for a [command handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548550/how-do-i-code-event-command-handlers-for-my-discord-js-bot/56548551#56548551).

Answer (score 0):

JSON is highly prone to corruption if a queue system is not created that will make sure multiple reads and writes are not happening to a file all at the same time. For the purpose of what you want, I would use something like SQLite that requires minimal setup, is easy to learn, and has helper frameworks to make it easier to use such as Keyv and Sequelize.

[Here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/) is a good guide on how to use sqlite in the nodejs runtime environment.

Comment: Databases are the much better option. I would recommend MongoDB for its speeds and native JS framework. However, the choices are unlimited. Also, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259), then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)